# Nothing received from recvfrom on windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, enet

I have some problems on Windows 8 using recvfrom. I have a socket which is bound to INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0), and i'd like to receive some packets on it.

The problem is that I see those packets in Wireshark, but recvfrom never tells me that the received size is greater than 0. I've tried biding the socket to 127.0.0.1 or even to my local IPv4 address, I never get anything. The port used is 7321 (locally)

I use the ENet library for the creation of the socket, and then I used that socket in recvfrom. Here's the code that never returns the expected packets.

```
uint8_t* buffer; // max size needed normally (only used for stun)
buffer = (uint8_t*)(malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*2048));
memset(buffer, 0, 2048);

socklen_t from_len;
struct sockaddr addr;

from_len = sizeof(addr);
int len = recvfrom(m_host->socket, (char*)buffer, 2048, 0, &addr, &from_len); //m_host is of type ENetHost, the socket in it is a file descriptor like standard sockets
```

As I said, it's a bit weird as Wireshark shows me the packets (which are STUN responses if you want to know).

Can someone help me find out what is missing that may be causing this issue?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently where Wireshark reported the packet and the application was listening, but it didn't receive the packet. Turns out it was the routing table. Maybe that's also your problem? (It was on Linux so I don't know how to check or fix it on Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addr` variable is declared as a `sockaddr`.  It needs to be declared as a `sockaddr_in` (works with IPv4 only) or `SOCKADDR_STORAGE` (works with both IPv4 and IPv6), and then typecast it to `sockaddr*` when passing it to `recvfrom()`.

Aside from that, you say that `recvfrom()` is not returning >= 0.  So what is it actually returning?  If it returns 0, then a 0-length packet was received (impossible for TCP, but possible for UDP). If it returns -1 (aka `SOCKET_ERROR`), then an error occured so use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out what that error actually is.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for helping :
first: using sockarrd_in first doesn't help, maybe because the recvfrom function waits a sockaddr* as the fifth parameter and not sockaddr_in*
second: always return -1. I'll try seing WSAGHetLastError() and will tell you what the result is.

Comment: I have the error "a non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately"

Comment: First, `recvfrom()` does not want a `sockaddr`, it wants whatever matches the underlying socket type - `sockaddr_in` for IPv4, `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6, etc. If it really wanted `sockaddr` than the sixth parameter would not exist, but it does exist because the fifth parameter is actually variable-length. Second, `WSAGetLastError()` gives you an error code, not a string. The error message you stated suggests you are getting `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` (10035) as the error code, which is perfectly normal if you are using a non-blocking socket and there is no data available to read at that moment.

Comment: So if WireShark sees data arriving at your PC, but your socket is not receiving the data, then the OS is not routing the data to your socket. That means either you are not actually bound to the correct Protocol/IP/Port that the data was sent to (use WireShark to double-check not only the destination IP/Port, but also the packet type and destination MAC address of the inbound packet), or the data is being blocked before reaching your app, which itself might suggest either a firewall/antivirus issue or a misconfiguration in the OS routing tables.

Comment: Ok for the parameters of recvfrom, now i use sockaddr_in correctly. I have indeed the 10035 error. The thing i don't understand is that the socket is not blocking, but the function seems to never see the incoming data (which exists). The protocol pile is Ethernet/IP/UDP, and accordingly to ipconfig everything in the incoming packet is fine (ip, mac, right protocols).
For instance, i've tried to use a blocking socket (not setting the nonblock option) and I don't receive the packets either on 0.0.0.0:7321 (7321 being again the port used by the transaction)

Comment: You can't get a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error on a blocking socket, so you must be using the socket in non-blocking mode. And you can't send packets to 0.0.0.0, they have to be sent to a real IP (but you can bind to 0.0.0.0 to receive packets sent to any local IPv4 address that the machine owns).  So again, if the socket is not receiving the data, then either the socket is not actually bound to what the data is actually being sent to, or your system is misconfigured and not routing the data correctly at the OS layer.

Comment: So far, all you have shown is the code that reads the data, but you have not shown the code that creates and initializes the socket prior to reading.

Comment: To do that i use the ENet (library) function enet_host_create. The code behind is pretty long. But as it is a common library i assume the code that initializes the socket is fine. I will try to check routing tables in windows to see what is in it when i do those transactions

Comment: I am not familiar with ENet, but why are you reading behind ENet's back in the first place, and not letting ENet handle the reading for you? What if ENet reads the inboun data before you do your own read? That might account for the `recvfrom()` issue you are having.

Comment: Actually that was a thread problem. You ask why i don't use ENet to read data, it's essentially because i use the STUN protocol which does not let me use enet, obviously. The problem was that i was canceling the thread before reading the socket, but there is a delay between the cancel time and the time the thread really stops. Actually the ENet thread was still reading the packet when i was trying to read the socket myself. 
Thanks a lot for all your answers, which helped me clean my code.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 possible reasons you are having the problem:

1) You might not have the port correct on your sendto & recvfrom socket. So say you are sending packets to port 6000, but your recvfrom is listening on port 6001 or something. Just double check both programs are using the same port.

2) Windows firewall. I would run the program as an admin just to be safe, but also make sure you allow your program through windows firewall to communicate using private or public networks.

Comment: I have tried disabling all firewalls (antivir+windows) and checked ports. The socket is clearly listening on 0.0.0.0:7321 and wireshark tells me the packet arrives on port 7321, destination IP being 192.168.0.11 (my local ip address).